# How to use for loop to print data[1,1] then data[2,2] and so on

Tags: r, for-loop

Let's say I have a data frame like this:

```
data<-data.frame(
weight=c(64,52,78,90,123,83),
age=c(29,50,33,57,44,54),
height=c(170,184,162,190,179,171)
)
```

Now I would like to use a "for loop" to print the data [1,1], then data [2,2] and data [3,3]

With the following loop I get the data [1,1], [1,2] and [1,3].

```
for (c in 1:ncol(data)){
    print(data[1,c])
}
```

How do I modify it to obtain the above?

Answer (score 1):

Simply try this:

```
for (c in 1:ncol(data)){
 print(data[c,c])
 }
```

**OR**

If you are looking to access diagonal element then use `diag`

```
diag(as.matrix(data[,]))
```

Output:

```
[1]  64  50 162
```

Comment: Ohh, I see. Thank you so much for your help.